# Is a shaped iframe possible?

Tags: css, html, iframe

Is it possible to have an iframe in the shape of a hexagon or diamond or anything other than a rectangle or square?

Or possibly even a div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could fake it with a CSS mask.

But portions of it will be obscured by it. You can't make the `iframe` render its contents inside of one of these shapes.

Comment: Hmm... The content--except for the center 100x100px is there just for looks so yeah I guess I could just put an image in front of it hiding everything outside the shape.. Don't think I ever would have thought of something so simple... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could set an iframe shape (or, rather, an iframe container shape) to [something oval](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/eKm3C/2/) farily easy, however the problem with a diamond/hex shape is that you can't set *any* html element to render in that shape in the first place.

You could try using a mask as alex suggested.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. There is no posibilites in HTML standard to do this. You can wrap iframe with DIV and get some effects like rounded corners only

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use an image as a mask and then absolute position it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you want to support, you can use border radius, transparency, and other tricks [to create many shapes in css](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).