# How to bring a Google Maps' iframe in diamond shape?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe

I want to insert a google maps in a diamond shape into my website.
I tried to draw a white (site's background color) in each corner of the `iframe`.

The HTML and CSS look like this:

```css
body {
  background: teal
}
.wrapper {
  background: red
}
iframe {
  background: #000;
  height: 556px;
  width: 556px;
}
.triangles {
  position: absolute;
}
.top-left-triangle {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 288px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 288px solid transparent;
}
.bottom-left-triangle {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 288px solid yellow;
  border-top: 288px solid transparent;
}
.bottom-right-triangle {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 288px solid green;
  border-top: 288px solid transparent;
}
.top-right-triangle {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 288px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 288px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="triangles top-left-triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangles bottom-left-triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangles top-right-triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangles bottom-right-triangle"></div>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Needless to say that it made my `iframe` unclickable, so there's no reason to have a `iframe` instead a raw image, which I want do avoid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A quick google search brought this up: [Is a shaped iframe possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075893/is-a-shaped-iframe-possible)

Comment: I've turned your code into a testable snippet, and took the liberty of adding colors so we can see exactly what's happening. This is tangential to your question, but it looks to me like you probably meant to place the triangles differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support IE < 9, you should be able to keep the iframe clickable by adding `.triangles {pointer-events: none}` (support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events))

Comment: It did the trick. If I tried to hide it with CSS masks, it's still unclickable. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked!